# Magento 2 error when merging and minifying JS and CSS files

Tags: magento2.2

I merged and minified JS files and CSS files and now my Magento 2 is throwing below error:

`Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Magento\\Developer\\Model\\View\\Asset\\PreProcessor\\FrontendCompilation::processContent() must be an instance of Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\File\\FallbackContext, instance of Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\File\\Context given, called in vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php on line 90 and defined in vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php:107\nStack trace:\n#0 vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php(90): Magento\\Developer\\Model\\View\\Asset\\PreProcessor\\FrontendCompilation->processContent('c7e57e76387ecc5...', '@import 'source...', '', Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\File\\Context))\n#1 vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/PreprocessorStrategy.php(74)...\n'`

How to solve this?

Comment: Konstantin Gerasimov's comment helped me out. It as exactly the reason.
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

This is because you are using client-side LESS compilation.

Switch to server-side LESS compilation by running this SQL:

```
update core_config_data set value='server_side_compilation' where path='dev/front_end_development_workflow/type';
```

Comment: not sure how that is fixing the issue, what if I want to have FE compilation, that should still work right?

Answer (score 1):

- Now first check current application mode:developer Minification is not applied in developer mode so please apply this command and check it.

  `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

  `rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/*`

Comment: Is that the answer, about the minification? via the admin those options only appear in Developer mode, seems wrong that you can enable to them break the site.